# Is it possible to optimize performance in this part

Tags: performance, perl, subroutine, slowdown

I have a problem with performance in Perl. This is the code:
http://pastebin.com/jpmhv395

It might have problems in other places as well, but the main problem is in line 336: The anagram_hash method seems to be called very often.
The method actually is in a different module, here it is:
http://pastebin.com/5NRC4bs8

The subroutine should work differently depending on whether an integer or a string was passed as argument.

Is the subroutine 'anagram_hash' causing the poor performance, or do you see anything other that could cause a drop in performance? If so, how could it be optimized?

Comment: Wondering (without a deep study of the first pastebin) - why do you need calculate your anagram-hash this way? The `sum of num**5` has some special-need, or you simple want any unique "digest" (hash) from the supplied word?

Comment: I unfortunately cannot say at this moment. This is a project I've been thrown into recently, and I still haven't figured it all out.

Comment: Asking because using `use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex)` and `$hash = md5_hex($s)` is approx 7 times faster as the `anagram_hash` sub... (59k/sec vs 500k/sec on my notebook)

Comment: You got a point there. If it turns out this is just creating a unique digest, we might as well switch over to Digest::MD5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you could make a 256 element lookup table so you just do

```
$result += $lookup{$char};
```

instead of

```
my $temp = ord($char);
$result += $temp**5;
```

but you should really run the profiler to see what the problem is first... [here](https://metacpan.org/release/Devel-NYTProf).

EDIT (jm666 and ikegami) - Added the Benchmark example. As you can see by observing the results of power_goodloop and lookup_goodloop which vary only by whether exponentiation or a hash lookup is used, exponentiation is much faster. It's the poor loop that's slowing you down.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );
use Benchmark qw(:all);

my @lookup = map { $_ ** 5 } 0..255;
my %lookup = map { chr($_) => $_ ** 5 } 0..255;

my $str = join '', map chr(rand(256)), 1..1000;

say "test of the result";
say anagram_hash1($str);
say anagram_hash2($str);
say anagram_hash3($str);
say anagram_hash4($str);
say anagram_hash5($str);
say "";    
cmpthese(-3, {
    'power_badloop'    => sub { anagram_hash1($str) },
    'hlookup_badloop'  => sub { anagram_hash2($str) },
    'power_goodloop'   => sub { anagram_hash3($str) },
    'hlookup_goodloop' => sub { anagram_hash4($str) },
    'alookup_goodloop' => sub { anagram_hash5($str) },
});


sub anagram_hash1 {
        my $result = 0;
        my $s      = shift;
        my $length = length($s);
        if ( $s =~ /[a-zA-Z]+/ ) {
                for ( my $i = 0 ; $i < $length ; $i++ ) {
                        my $char = substr( $s, $i, 1 );
                        my $temp = ord($char);
                        $result += $temp**5;
                }
        } elsif ( $s =~ /^[\d]+$/ ) {
                my $temp = int($s);
                $result += $temp**5;
        } else {
                die "Invalid parameter passed to method 'anagram_hash'\nExpected: String or Number\nPassed: $s";
        }
        return $result;
}
sub anagram_hash2 {
        my $result = 0;
        my $s      = shift;
        my $length = length($s);
        if ( $s =~ /[a-zA-Z]+/ ) {
                for ( my $i = 0 ; $i < $length ; $i++ ) {
                        my $char = substr( $s, $i, 1 );
                        $result += $lookup{$char};
                }
        } elsif ( $s =~ /^[\d]+$/ ) {
                my $temp = int($s);
                $result += $temp**5;
        } else {
                die "Invalid parameter passed to method 'anagram_hash'\nExpected: String or Number\nPassed: $s";
        }
        return $result;
}

sub anagram_hash3 {
        my $result = 0;
        my $s      = shift;
        if ( $s =~ /[a-zA-Z]/ ) {
                $result += $_ ** 5 for unpack "C*", $s;
        } elsif ( $s =~ /^[\d]+$/ ) {
                $result += int($s) ** 5;
        } else {
                die "Invalid parameter passed to method 'anagram_hash'\nExpected: String or Number\nPassed: $s";
        }
        return $result;
}

sub anagram_hash4 {
        my $result = 0;
        my $s      = shift;
        if ( $s =~ /[a-zA-Z]/ ) {
                $result += $lookup{$_} for unpack "(a)*", $s;
        } elsif ( $s =~ /^[\d]+$/ ) {
                $result += int($s) ** 5;
        } else {
                die "Invalid parameter passed to method 'anagram_hash'\nExpected: String or Number\nPassed: $s";
        }
        return $result;
}

sub anagram_hash5 {
        my $result = 0;
        my $s      = shift;
        if ( $s =~ /[a-zA-Z]/ ) {
                $result += $lookup[$_] for unpack "C*", $s;
        } elsif ( $s =~ /^[\d]+$/ ) {
                $result += int($s) ** 5;
        } else {
                die "Invalid parameter passed to method 'anagram_hash'\nExpected: String or Number\nPassed: $s";
        }
        return $result;
}
```

Output:

```
test of the result
171658778879381
171658778879381
171658778879381
171658778879381
171658778879381

                   Rate power_badloop hlookup_badloop hlookup_goodloop power_goodloop alookup_goodloop
power_badloop    2132/s            --            -25%             -35%           -71%             -74%
hlookup_badloop  2826/s           33%              --             -14%           -62%             -66%
hlookup_goodloop 3294/s           55%             17%               --           -56%             -60%
power_goodloop   7446/s          249%            163%             126%             --             -10%
alookup_goodloop 8298/s          289%            194%             152%            11%               --
```

So, the results showing:

- the original OP's code is the slowest
- the second is Mark's solution (replacing both of ord/exp with the hash lookup) - so, the Mark's solution is *FASTER* than the original OP's code.

finally, (as usually) Ikegami comes with 3 solutions what are *much* faster as the any of previous. :)

Comment: What a brilliant answer! I must admit, I'm a bit ashamed I didn't think of pre-computing the values! And thanks for the profiler link! I'm sure it will be helpful in the future!

Comment: `$lookup{$char}` I think you mean

Comment: @ikegami Would you mind elaborating please? I believe you mean the OP's for loop and substr() can be replaced by unpack(), but the point of suggesting the lookup was to avoid the exponentiation

Comment: @jm666, You might be, but that's irrelevant. Hash lookup is slower than exponentionation. Replacing the exponentionation with a hash lookup is wrong. You're arguing that two wrongs make a right. It doesn't matter what ord+exp is, **it's wrong to use a hash lookup as Mark Setchell suggested**. I don't know how that's out of context.